Getting different bootsplash icon than the one that was used by generating react-native-bootsplash
We migrated from react-native-bootsplash-v4 to react-native-bootsplash-v6 for the dark-splash support. The CLI generated the required assets using the logo provided. The background color is changed however we are getting a different logo instead of the one used in the parameter while generating the assets
Few information that might be helpful:

Migrated app from RN 0.65 to 0.72
Changed everything as per given in the documentation

This issue is only happening on android

The following changes resolved the issue

Deleted all the bootsplash_logo.png from mipmap-xx folders
Changed values in styles.xml in folder named values and values-night to the following

<!-- BootTheme should inherit from Theme.BootSplash or Theme.BootSplash.EdgeToEdge -->
    <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.BootSplash">
        <item name="bootSplashBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
        <item name="bootSplashLogo">@drawable/bootsplash_logo</item>
        <item name="postBootSplashTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
<!-- The following code helps in hiding the white circle that comes up in bootsplash-->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>


Also changed the following line in MainActivity.java

 -         RNBootSplash.init(this);
 -         RNBootSplash.init(this, R.style.BootTheme);

Source: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/blob/5.5.3/MIGRATION.md
